# Sub-query same column with different criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to write a sub-query to retrieve values from one of the columns I already selected with the main query, but under different criteria.

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AB9LP.png)

Comment: We need to see your query for that. Also, why is the 2nd line in the desired result? That is a "Credit" type and not "Charge type".

Comment: Correct it should be "Credit", my mistake.

Comment: You mean, it should be "Charge" type, right?

Comment: it should be: Amazon 500.00 type "Credit" and charge null

Comment: Then, that's not what your expected result shows.

Comment: Please edit the question and add your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (thedate date, customer VARCHAR(100), revenue INT, [type] VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO #temp values ('2019-01-01','Acme, Inc.',1000,'Charge')
                        ,('2019-01-01','Amazon',500,'Charge')
                        ,('2019-01-01','Acme, Inc.',100,'Credit')

SELECT [Date]
    , [Customer]
    , [Revenue] as [Charge]
    , [Credit]
FROM #temp t1
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT sum(revenue) credit
    FROM #temp t2
    WHERE t1.customer = t2.customer
        AND t2.[type] = 'credit'
    ) x
WHERE t1.[type] = 'charge'
```

Judging solely based on your input data and expected result, the above query should suffice. However, the comments you posted on your question are slightly contradictory with what the image of the expected result shows.

This is the output of my query, based on your input data:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this, I think you can use sub queries for Charge and Credit:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       [date],[customer],
       Charge = (SELECT Revenue FROM TABLE t2 WHERE t2.customer = t1.customer AND t2.[type] = 'Charge'), 
       Credit = (SELECT Revenue FROM TABLE t2 WHERE t2.customer = t1.customer AND t2.[type] = 'Credit')
FROM TABLE t1
```

With example data:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (thedate date, customer VARCHAR(100), revenue INT, [type] VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO #temp values ('2019-01-01','a',10,'charge'),('2019-01-01','a',20,'Credit'),('2019-01-01','b',30,'charge')

SELECT DISTINCT
       [thedate], [customer],
       Charge = (SELECT Revenue FROM #temp t2 WHERE t2.customer = t1.customer AND t2.[type] = 'Charge'), 
       Credit = (SELECT Revenue FROM #temp t2 WHERE t2.customer = t1.customer AND t2.[type] = 'Credit')
FROM #temp t1
```

Comment: Based on his existing data, this could work, however, it doesn't return the **exact** desired result. It actually returns more rows. I think we're missing some information about the required result.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu Hi Radu. In which condition it would return more rows than expected I couldn't see, but we might have missing information from the OP I agree with that.

Comment: `FROM TABLE t1`, there is no condition that FILTERS and returns only 2 rows. However, I noticed that you just added DISTINCT (which gives you the desired result), but is more of a specific scenario fix. If the user adds more columns to the query, `DISTINCT` might not do the job.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (thedate date, customer VARCHAR(100), revenue INT, [type] VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO #temp values ('2019-01-01','Acme, Inc.',1000,'Charge')
                        ,('2019-01-01','Amazon',500,     'CREDIT')
                        ,('2019-01-01','Acme, Inc.',100, 'Credit')


SELECT  THEDATE,
        CUSTOMER,
        MAX(CASE
            WHEN TYPE = 'CREDIT' THEN revenue
        END) AS CREDIT,
        MAX(CASE
            WHEN TYPE = 'CHARGE' THEN REVENUE
        END) AS CHARGE
FROM #TEMP
GROUP BY CUSTOMER, THEDATE
```

Or you could try PIVOT Function

```
SELECT  *
FROM #TEMP
PIVOT (MAX(REVENUE)
        FOR 
        [TYPE] IN ([CHARGE],[CREDIT])
        ) AS PIV
```

Comment: `Max` Could be replaced with any other aggregations you're trying to make.